# Do mails sent with PHP Mailer send automatically when the connection is correct?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I would like to ask what happens if the PHP Mailer library fails to send an email via SMTP. The service connects to the SMTP server but emails are not send at all. Do these email go to some kind of queue and are send when the problem is solved or will I have to resend them once more from the code?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What does mail() method returns? If true, PHP job is done. Probably posting your code might help finding the issue if any.

Comment: the send() method of the PHP Mailer class returned false. the thing i need to know is whether this failed mail will be sent automatically later or if I need to send it again

Comment: No it wont be sent. It failed before reaching mail server. Hence, you need to check your configurations for SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

As far as PHPMailer is concerned, messages are either sent or they are not; it does no queuing of its own because it's not a mail server. Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` to see the whole conversation with your mail server. It may be that your mail server does queue, and may take a while to deal with onward delivery, but that's beyond the control of PHPMailer. Your mail server logs (if you have access to them) will also tell you what it's doing. All of this is covered in the PHPMaielr docs.